# Side By Side ClickOnce Installations

Tags: .net, winforms, testing, .net-3.5, clickonce

I would like to deploy a TEST version of my internal application to my testing group and I need it to install side by side with the current LIVE version.

I changed everything in the Publish Options but it STILL overwrites my LIVE install.  What else do I need to do?  Do I have to change the Assembly Name on the Application Tab?  Is that even something I should be doing?  Seems like that'd break things.

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing with Visual Studio has lots of limitations.  [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55.aspx) is a decent alternative as long as you are signing your deployments.  Last I checked, MageUI can't create unsigned deployments.

In MageUI, all you need to change is the 'Name' field of your deployment manifest (the one with the .application extension).  This should change your Application Identity and allow you to install it alongside your production version.

Another thing I've seen others do but haven't resorted to myself, is changing the assembly name.  Add "Test" to your assembly name and the ClickOnce product name and it should install separately.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to assume OP is publishing via Visual Studio. I publish using msbuild script and I have the same issue

Comment: @PandaWood "I changed everything in the **Publish Options** but it STILL overwrites my LIVE install. Do I have to change the Assembly Name on the **Application tab**?" The "Publish Options" dialog and "Application tab" are all part of [the project property page in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPX21.png). Seems pretty clear they're using it.

Answer (score 4):

Change the assembly name and the Product name (so you can distinguish between the versions on the start menu).

You can muck with the deployment name, but frankly, it's more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common requirment. Here are two ways that have worked for me:

1 -  provide different deployment name for each build.

```
<MSBuild Projects="ClickOnce.csproj"
   Targets="Publish"
   Properties="
        MinimumRequiredVersion=$(MinimumRequiredVersion);
        ApplicationVersion=$(ApplicationVersion);
        ApplicationRevision=$(ApplicationRevision);
        CodeBranch=$(CodeBranch);
        DeployEnv=$(DeployEnv)
        AssemblyName=ClickOnce.$(DeployEnv);
        PublishUrl=$(PublishUrl);
        ProductName=ClickOnce $(CodeBranch) $(DeployEnv)" />
```

The one limitation of this approach is that project references will no longer work. 
Use file based assembly refs, and it'll be fine.

2 -  Use a code signing certificate
For a more polished look obtain one from a trusted root. Instead of getting an install dialog that says "Unknown publisher", you can indicate the name of your group. It also lets the auditors feel warm and fuzzy.